# Css - Keyframes and animation webkit issue

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I seem to have an issue with the webkit animations. I added an overlay spinner. This one shows fine on every browser (Mozilla, IE, Edge, Chrome). On Andriod and iPhone/iPad the animation is not fired. Am I missing something in my code?
In CSS I added following to the div of the element:

```
-webkit-animation-name:webkit-rotate-scale;  
-webkit-animation-duration:0.75s;  
-webkit-animation-direction:normal;  
-webkit-animation-delay:0s;  
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;  
-webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;  
-webkit-animation-play-state:running;
```

and

```
@-webkit-keyframes webkit-rotate-scale {  
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);}  
    50% {-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) scale(.5);}  
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);}  
}
```

Off course I added the standard (no webkit) alternatives also.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

The div where I am showing it in has display: inline-block.

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Jerry

Comment: your code seems ok . try to clear cache and run it again

Comment: Dear, Mihai, I'm afraid that didn't help. Any other suggestions?